# Cannot convert np.array from bool to uint8 and save image properly with opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have the following image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg3V0.png)

I am reading the image in, performing some image processing, and then saving the image back to the folder. In between, I have to convert the image to bool.

When I try to convert back to uint8, and save it, I am returned the following image:

[black image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4HWt.png)

The code to reproduce this is here:

```
import cv2
R = cv2.imread('R.png')
R = R.astype(dtype=bool)
R = R.astype(dtype='uint8')
cv2.imwrite('rr.png',R)
```

Comment: I know nothing about `opencv`, but it looks to me as though the conversion to `bool` results in a black image and my best guess is that the white balance is off, i.e. the background in R.png isn't actually white so it gets converted to black in the `bool` conversion.

Comment: The output is an image with 0s and 1s, while the full intensity range is 0-255. When displayed, intensity of 1 will be hardly recognizable from intensity of 0. The only problem here is your expectation of what that data saved as an 8bit grayscale image will look like.

Comment: In fact it's not even a grayscale image, since you're using `cv2.imread` with the second argument left at default, which loads it as BGR. It doesn't matter anyway, since it's still full of zeros and ones, so it will look all black when displayed.

Comment: Multiply by 255, clip to range 0-255, and then convert to uint8

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV doesn't recognize a boolean array, and doesn't have a special type for binary image. It uses a uint8 array with values 0 and 255 instead. When converting the boolean array to uint8, you get an array with values of 0 and 1. You need to multiply this by 255 to get an array that OpenCV will recognize as a binary image:

```py
R = R.astype(dtype='uint8')
R *= 255
```